# Draw cursor multiple display (only draw text icon) GDI

Tags: winapi, screenshot, gdi, mousecapture

I select displays in multiple display environments and produce captured programs.

And try to draw a cursor by selecting dc among multiple displays.

I draw cursors with bitblt bitmap images and it works well.

```
HDC HDCC = CreateDC((L"Display"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

But When I select from createDC multuple display value,

```
DISPLAY_DEVICEW info = { 0 };
info.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICEW);
EnumDisplayDevicesW(NULL, 0, &info, EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME); 
HDCC = CreateDC(info.DeviceName, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I am working hard to get other display images. But there is no drawing cursor. (Other forms of cursor are not drawn, only text cursor is drawn)

This is my code.

```
const int d_count = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS);  //I have 3 display and count is 3.
HDC hCaptureDC;
HDC HDCC;
HBITMAP hBitmap;
HGDIOBJ hOld;
BYTE *src;


bool GetMouse() {
     CURSORINFO cursor = { sizeof(cursor) };
     ::GetCursorInfo(&cursor);

     ICONINFOEXW info = { sizeof(info) };
     ::GetIconInfoExW(cursor.hCursor, &info);

     BITMAP bmpCursor = { 0 };
     GetObject(info.hbmColor, sizeof(bmpCursor), &bmpCursor);

     POINT point;
     GetCursorPos(&point);

     bool res = DrawIconEx(hCaptureDC, point.x, point.y, cursor.hCursor, bmpCursor.bmWidth, bmpCursor.bmHeight, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);
     return res;
}

void screencap(){
    BITMAPINFO MyBMInfo;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHeader;
    HWND m_hWndCopy= GetDesktopWindow();
    GetClientRect(m_hWndCopy, &ImageRect);  
    const int nWidth = ImageRect.right - ImageRect.left; 
    const int nHeight = ImageRect.bottom - ImageRect.top;

    MyBMInfo = { 0 };
    MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader);

    bmpInfoHeader = { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) };
    bmpInfoHeader.biWidth = nWidth;
    bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = nHeight;
    bmpInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = 32;

    b_size = ((nWidth * bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * nHeight;

     //HDCC = CreateDC((L"Display"), NULL, NULL, NULL);   //It's good.
    DISPLAY_DEVICEW info = { 0 };
    info.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICEW);
    EnumDisplayDevicesW(NULL, 0, &info, EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME); 
    HDCC = CreateDC(info.DeviceName, NULL, NULL, NULL);   // It draws only text cursor.

    hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(HDCC);
    hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(HDCC, nWidth, nHeight);
    hOld = SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hBitmap);

    BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, HDCC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    GetMouse();

    SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hOld);

    src = (BYTE*)malloc(b_size);
    if (GetDIBits(hCaptureDC, hBitmap, 0, nHeight, src, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmpInfoHeader, DIB_RGB_COLORS)) {
        if (RGBSaveBMP(src) == true) 
        free(src);
    }  
}
```

I'm using windows 10.

How can I solved?

Any links, idea, Thanks.

ADD

It does not draw cursor....(except text cursor.)

```
HDCC = CreateDC(TEXT("\\\\.\\Display1"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

[image: HDCC = CreateDC(TEXT("\\.\Display1"), NULL, NULL, NULL);]

It draws cursor..

```
HDCC = CreateDC(TEXT("Display"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

[image: HDCC = CreateDC(TEXT("Display"), NULL, NULL, NULL);]

SOLVED:

Now, I changed my algorithm.

CreateDC(L"Display", NULL, NULL, NULL) create DC for all monitors, so what is your problem? – user2120666 Apr 22 at 15:37

This comment is very helpful but It was not kind. (Or I was stupid.)  :(

```
HDC HDCC = CreateDC((L"Display"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

HDCC has "All Virtual Screens" DC.

When I selected the monitor I needed, and accordingly selected and used the area to capture on the virtual screen.

```
HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(HDCC);  
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(HDCC, nWidth, nHeight);
HDC HDCC = CreateDC((L"Display"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
DEVMODE dev;

std::string str = "\\\\.\\Display" + std::to_string(select);
std::wstring temp;
temp.assign(str.begin(), str.end());

EnumDisplaySettingsW(temp.c_str(), ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dev);
printf("Display%d : (%d * %d) (%d, %d)\n", select, dev.dmPelsWidth, dev.dmPelsHeight, dev.dmPosition.x, dev.dmPosition.y);

nWidth = dev.dmPelsWidth;
nHeight = dev.dmPelsHeight;
nposx = dev.dmPosition.x;
nposy = dev.dmPosition.y;

hOld = SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hBitmap);
BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, HDCC, nposx, nposy, SRCCOPY);
int colorcheck = GetSystemMetrics(SM_SAMEDISPLAYFORMAT);

CURSORINFO cursor = { sizeof(cursor) };
bool check = ::GetCursorInfo(&cursor);
bool check2 = ::GetCursorInfo(&cursor);
int count = ShowCursor(TRUE);

info = { sizeof(info) };
::GetIconInfoExW(cursor.hCursor, &info);

GetCursorPos(&point);

if (point.x > nWidth) {
    point.x = point.x - nWidth;
}
else if (point.x < 0) {
    point.x = nWidth + point.x;
}
if (point.y > nHeight) {
    point.y = point.y - nHeight;
}
else if (point.y < 0) {
    point.y = nHeight + point.y;
}
cursor.ptScreenPos.x = point.x;
cursor.ptScreenPos.y = point.y;

bool res = ::DrawIconEx(hCaptureDC, point.x, point.y, cursor.hCursor, 0, 0, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);


BYTE* src = (BYTE*)malloc(b_size);
GetDIBits(hCaptureDC, hBitmap, 0, nHeight, src, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmpInfoHeader, DIB_RGB_COLORS)
```

Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. And since you are looking for help, you need to make it easy for us to help you. Properly formatting the code goes a long way.

Comment: CreateDC(L"Display", NULL, NULL, NULL) create DC for all monitors, so what is your problem?

Comment: @IInspectable I edited my question. I am sorry if U do not understand. I was very tired. :)

Comment: @user2120666 It worked well on a single display. However, when capturing the screen with multiple displays and drawing the cursor, it is not drawn.

Comment: Can you publish two pictures for comparison?

Comment: @Strive Sun - MSFT  I Add pictures... thanks.

Comment: @Birds hello, Birds, your problem hasn't been solved yet, has it? You seem to have tried my method, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT Sun - MSFT Yes. I did. So I change method. 
Now, I get DC of virtual screen and set BitBlt capture area individually based on monitor index and I use it. The explanation of my method will update the answer later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call `GetClientRect(m_hWndCopy, &ImageRect);` is wrong.

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/multiple-monitor-system-metrics):

> The rectangle of the desktop window returned by GetWindowRect or
>   GetClientRect is always equal to the rectangle of the primary monitor,
>   for compatibility with existing applications.

So you are capturing only primary display.

Comment: It is working to get Display2 image. but It does not draw cursor. (Other forms of cursors are not drawn. Only draws text cursor) Sorry. I forgot to describe my situation.

Comment: Your cursor is over edit box, maybe because this show caret cursor.

Comment: And, why are other types of cursors not displayed?

Comment: It shouldn't matter where the cursor is.

Answer (score 0):

Following [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaymonitors) to get `EnumDisplayMonitor` may solve your problem.

> Use EnumDisplayMonitors to get the device name and pass it to
>   CreateDC.

Comment: I can get a second display image. However, you can not draw the cursor. Is this answer relevant?

Comment: @Birds Because I don't have multiple monitors to test, but I get this conclusion by consulting the data. You can try it. I hope it can help you.